# WebView doesn't align top or bottom in its container

Tags: android, webview, alignment

I have a strange problem.

I have an ImageView and on this ImageView is a WebView. This WebView ist as big as the ImageView an its background is transparent so that only the text is displayed by the WebView.

On my Galaxy Nexus this works perfectly.
But on my Sony Xperia, the WebView doesn't align the top and the bottom of the image. Left an Right alignment is O.K.

But why is this like this?

Here is my xml-code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/product_pic_background" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/produkttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"           
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Xperia arc . how it shouldn't be]

[image: Galaxy Nexus. how it should be]

1.Xperia arc. how it shouldn't be
  2.Galaxy Nexus. how it should be

Comment: Use `dip` instead of `dp` and see if it will give you different results :)

Comment: Can you please paste screenshots from both the devices and paste here the exact models of those devices. Thanks

Comment: add the 2 pictures...

Comment: If I understood correctly, make `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of the `ImageView`. If that fails, which I doubt, then include the `ImageView` in the `RelativeLayout` maybe ?

Comment: From the last edit you made: "1.Xperia arc. how it shouldn't be 2.Galaxy Nexus. how it should be" - which one should it be - I guess the first one. If you want the text to be "limited" (enclosed) by the image "frame", then you should add them both in the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: It should be enclosed. And yes I add the IV to the    Relative Layout but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, one solution to this, once we have the requirements:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="50dip" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/produkttext"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@+drawable/product_pic_background"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the code:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.produkttext);
web.setBackgroundColor(0);
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.product_pic_background);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
rl.getLayoutParams().height = bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
rl.getLayoutParams().width = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
```

This will make the `WebView` transparent, so to see the background image, as well as to match the parent layout by width and height.
Then, the `RelativeLayout` will be set with the dimensions of the picture's drawable.
I haven't manage to test it (I can't at the moment), but if this doesn't work, I will delete this comment (and will possibly commit harakiri :-)).

Comment: your idea is very smart. but now it's scaling with the whole pic

Comment: wasn't that the idea- the "frame" to be as big as the picture and the text to be scrollable in it ?

Comment: the webview should be as big as the picture.

Comment: with your idea the text-webview is still scaling like in the first picture

Comment: That superposition is hard to obtain, but you can get the size of the picture in the program  and set the dimensions of the `WebView`. I will edit my reply later with the correct result.

Comment: Phew .. we did it! Cheers